# Making a call using values from a Textview

Tags: android, textview

I'm try to make a user make a phone call using values from a textview. the problem is that startActivity is undefined for the type View.onClicklistener. I'm trying to implement this in the lazyadapter get view class could someone please help me. Here is the code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text3=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);



        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).Name);
    holder.text3.setText(list.get(position).phone);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(", Address: " + list.get(position).address);

    holder.text3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
      String phonee="tel:"+ holder.text3.getText().toString().trim();
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phonee));
        startActivity(intent);//error is here

        }
    });

    holder.text2.setText(sb.toString());
    holder.image.setTag(data[position]);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.image);
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code instead

```
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: hey so it works but i it appends numbers that i have no ideea where they are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It works perfect to me..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
            intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", NUMBER, NUMBER));// Number is string variable..
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

And Did you give PHONE permission to your app?

You need to provide that into your AndroidManifest.xml

It is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="aexp.explistemptygroup">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> 
 <application>
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks....

Comment: It's the way I do it every time using MyActivity.this ;)

Comment: i have tried adding my activity name but i still get the error and yes i added the permissions in the manifest i don't know whats wrong any other approach please